# How to get the value from one function to other function in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 functions which will be execute on page load,I am getting a value in load1() function that I need to print into other function load2(). I am getting that one but with compilation error 'expected 0 arguments got 1', Can anyone please help me on it.

### Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<div>How to get the value from one function to other function in angular 6</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
declare var require: any;
import { Component,OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    data:any;
    idVal:number;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.load1();
  }
load1(){
    let data = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}];
    this.idVal = data[0].id;
    this.load2(this.idVal);
}
load2(){
    alert('load2');
    console.log(this.idVal);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written on that block of code, `load2()` does not have any required arguments.

Therefore, it returns that error when you try to pass an argument on it.

You can fix that issue by removing that argument on the last line of `load1()`.

```
load1(){
    let data = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}];
    this.idVal = data[0].id;
    this.load2();
}

load2(){
    alert('load2');
    console.log(this.idVal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
load1(){
    let data = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}];
    this.idVal = data[0].id;
    this.load2(this.idVal);
}

load2(idVal: number){
    alert('load2');
    console.log(idVal);
}
```

Comment: in this case how to get separately id and name load1(){
 let data = [{"id":1,"name":"one"},{"id":2,"name":"two"},{"id":3,"name":"three"}];
 this.idVal =  data[0].id;
 this.idVal2 = data[0].name;
 this.load2(this.idVal);
 this.load2(this.idVal2);
}
load2(idVal,idVal2){ 
 //alert('load2');
 console.log(idVal);
 
}

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
load1(){
    data = [{"id":1, name: "Ben Racicot"},{"id":2, name: "Some Guy"},{"id":3, name: "Some Girl"}];
    firstID = data[0].id; // the first object's `id` value: `1`  
    firstName = data[0].name; // the first object's name value: `Ben Racicot`

    this.load2(firstID, firstName);
}

load2(id, name){
    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
}
```